# Can I debug a PostgreSQL query sent from an external source, that I can't edit?

Tags: postgresql, debugging, postgis

I see how to debug queries stored as Functions in the database. But my problem is with an external QGIS plugin that connects to my Postgres 10.4 via network and does a complex query and calculations, and stores the results back into PostGIS tables:

```
FOR r IN c LOOP
    SELECT
        (1 - ST_LineLocatePoint(path.geom, ST_Intersection(r.geom, path.geom))) * ST_Length(path.geom)
    INTO
        station
(continues ...)
```

When it errors, it just returns that line number as the failing location, but no clue where it was in the loop through hundreds of features. (And any features it has processed are not stored to the output tables when it fails.) I totally don't know enough about the plugin and about SQL to hack the external query, and I suspect if it was a reasonable task the plugin author would have included more revealing debug messages.

So is there some way I could use pgAdmin4 (or anything) from the server side to watch the query process? Even being able to see if it fails the first time through the loop or later would help immensely. Knowing the loop count at failure would point me to the exact problem feature. Being able to see "station" or "r.geom" would make it even easier.

Perfectly fine if the process is miserably slow or interferes with other queries, I'm the only user on this server.

Comment: what do you see in the postgresql log file?

Comment: `auto_explain` can prove helpful if you set `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on`. It may not show you the failing statement, but the ones before. That can help to figure out where you are.

Comment: @Jasen The default log file showed exactly the messages relayed by my RiverGIS client app, error statement but no clues about its execution. I set up the auto_explain.log_nested_statements extension per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html, and it provides delicious data about successful calls - Seq Scan on "MendoFEMA"."XSCutLines" xs  (cost=0.00..13.70 rows=370 width=126) (actual time=0.012..0.230 rows=507 loops=1), but when an error happens only the same old error message is saved.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe I set up the auto_explain extension with nested_statements per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html, and it provides delicious data about successful calls - Seq Scan on "MendoFEMA"."XSCutLines" xs  (cost=0.00..13.70 rows=370 width=126) (actual time=0.012..0.230 rows=507 loops=1), but when an error happens only the same old error message is saved. Pretty sure I had everything enabled...  Oh, well...

Comment: Like I wrote: *It may not show you the failing statement, but the ones before. That can help to figure out where you are.*

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a way to watch the RiverGIS query in action, but it is the best I have found. It extracts the failing ST_Intersects() call from the RiverGIS code and runs it under your control, where you can display any clues you want.

When you're totally mystified where the RiverGIS problem might be, run this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    xs."XsecID" AS "XsecID",
    xs."ReachID" AS "ReachID",
    xs."Station" AS "Station",
    xs."RiverCode" AS "RiverCode",
    xs."ReachCode" AS "ReachCode",
    ST_Intersection(xs.geom, riv.geom) AS "Fraction"
FROM
    "<your project name>"."StreamCenterlines" AS riv,
    "<your project name>"."XSCutLines" AS xs
WHERE
    ST_Intersects(xs.geom, riv.geom)
ORDER BY xs."ReachID" ASC, xs."Station" DESC
```

Obviously replace `<your project name>` with the QGIS project name.

Also works for the BankLines step if you replace "StreamCenterlines" with "BankLines". Probably could be adapted to other situations where ST_Intersects() fails without a clue.

You'll get a listing with shorter geometry strings for good cross sections and double-length strings for bad ones. Probably need to widen your display column a lot to see this.

Works for me in pgAdmn4, or in QGIS3 -> Database -> DB Manager -> (click the wrench icon). You could select only bad lines, but I find the background info helpful.